# Black screen on start-up with cursor (graphical issue)

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, start-screen

since I upgraded to Windows 10 I am experiencing the following problem on my laptop. After I log in the computer screen is 90% black (the log in screen is normal and the 10% that is not black belongs to the taskbar but it doesn't contain the icons it should and the post-its I have in the upper left corner of the screen). I am sure everything is loaded in the background but in order to see my normal desktop I would normally have to open my Chrome browser (I know by heart where it is even though the screen is black) or the task manager and drag it over the screen as if I was "colouring it" in order to make the black areas disappear (surprisingly if I make a print screen everything seems normal as such I made a photo with my Mobile phone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/45jdE.jpg). I believe the matter is a graphical issue, but I don't have enough knowledge to know how to solve it.

The computer I use is a Lenovo X1 Carbon laptop, running Windows 10 with an Intel HD Graphic 5000.

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update hardware drivers, including GPU. Using Windows Update or you can manually check/download it from the manufacturer's website.

**Automatically get recommended drivers and updates for your hardware**:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15054/windows-7-automatically-get-recommended-drivers-updates-hardware

**How to: Install and Update Hardware Drivers in Windows 10**:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_devices/how-to-install-and-update-drivers-in-windows-10/a97bbbd1-9973-4d66-9a5b-291300006293